# "Сор" и "мусор"

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Попалось на одном из обсуждений. Слова "сор" и "мусор" однокоренные, корень "сор". Но тогда что, есть приставка "му-"?

Comment: меньше тащите сюда всякий мусор ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти слова не являются однокоренными. И происхождение у них разное.

Слово **МУСОР** с большой долей вероятности является тюркизмом - от *бусор, бусырь, бусорь* "хлам, старье" (при этом чередование б//м не являются чем-то из ряда вон выходящим). Версия происхождения от *mouds-, родственно греч. μύσος ср. р. "загрязнение, осквернение", μυσαρός "гнусный, покрытый позором", др.-ирл. mоsасh "нечистый" (*mudsāko-), нж.-нем. mussig "грязный", которой придерживается Фасмер, по мнению О.Н.Трубачева, иллюзорна.

Слово **СОР** в ближайшей этимологии имеет слова *серу, срать* (по Фасмеру). Дальнейшая связь с греч. skоr, род. п. σκωρ "кал, нечистоты", σκατός "отходы, шлак", др.-исл. skarn ср. р. "навоз, удобрение", нж.-нем. scharn "навоз, помет", хетт. «аkаr, род. п. «аknа« "грязь" неясна. Но ср. др.-инд. араskаrаs "нечистоты" и *скаред*.

Как видите, никакой приставки *му-* в слове *мусор* нет и не было.